# How do I view the status of my msql query?

Tags: php, mysql

I recently executed a mysql query via chrome and closed it out. How exactly does a browser stop a PHP script using the stop button? I thought PHP was a server-side language and could not be controlled through a client.

*UPDATE*I'm now aware of `SHOW PROCESSLIST`, but this only shows you which threads are running.Is there a SQL command I can use to view a executed query with great detail?

Comment: Counter-question: Do you know the difference between server-side and client-side programming?

Comment: well, no. your php script most likely terminated anyway (max runtime/required memory). If you want to work in a mysql-database and your inserts really take this long... please directly login to the mysql-service via bash/terminal (edit, or with some sort of GUI-tool)

Comment: Why the downvote? It is a perfectly reasonable question IMO

Comment: Yes I know the difference between server-side and client-side. I'm fluent in Javascript and PHP. "SHOW PROCESSLIST;" was the latent answer I was awaiting for, just thought I might take a more interesting approach on my question getting there.

Comment: @CodeMonkey This is lesson one stuff and should be crystal clear before even start coding some server side application. I fact I can't even imagine how to not understand the difference between an HTTP client and a MySQL server. Downvotes are also for "questions that do not show any research effort". In this case the answer is just a quick web-search away.

Comment: @feeela I want to come and work with you! Because I have come across a surprisingly high number of webfolks for whom this is not common knowledge :( Though the difficult grey area about what classes a good beginners question is one I am not sure I want to touch. +1 for addressing my concerns :)

Comment: @feeela the difference between a client and the database server is *not* what the OP is asking about.

Comment: @Pekka웃 Sure, not directly. But if you know the difference, IMO you could derive the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A client (Chrome) has nothing to do with the execution of scripts (PHP) on the server, which in turn have no control over database processes (MySQL query).

Look at your servers process list to see what's going on in general (Apache processes).

Or even better: use `SHOW PROCESSLIST;` on the MySQL console to find the long running query. You may quit it by using `KILL ###ID_OF_QUERY###;`.

Comment: SHOW PROCESSLIST; that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need to keep it open. If you exit a running car, does the car turn off? No.

Sorry, that came off a little snotty, but it wasn't intended too.

The browser, in your case Chrome, is not actually running the actual code. The server is. Thus, once the instruction is executed, closing the browser no longer matters as the request has been given to the server.

Comment: but it will slow down, a php script wont ; )

Comment: I hope that no one would exit a moving vehicle...regardless whether it is on or off.

Comment: @Christopher http://www.dailymail.co.uk/tvshowbiz/article-358451/Harvey-blames-potatoes-bizarre-car-accident.html

Answer (score 0):

two functions are essential for executing time consuming php scripts.
it has nothing to do with the browser (as other users already pointed out)

lookup [ignore_user_abort](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ignore-user-abort.php) and [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)

Comment: Does this really count for HTTP clients? As of the documentation it sounds like this is only available for scripts started via CLI (`ignore_user_abort`).

Answer (score 0):

The script will continue to execute regardless of browser closure. You can free up your browser by sending the response and allowing the php process to continue on.

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
$response = "Processing!"; 
header("Connection: close");
header("Content-Length: " . mb_strlen($response));
echo $response;
flush();

// Insert your lengthy query here
```

Comment: i like that method, still needs set_time_limit though, 30 seconds default arent enough for him

Answer (score 0):

Come on guys, this is PHP 101. Quoted from the manual:

> You can decide whether or not you want a client disconnect to cause
>   your script to be aborted. Sometimes it is handy to always have your
>   scripts run to completion even if there is no remote browser receiving
>   the output. The default behaviour is however for your script to be
>   aborted when the remote client disconnects.

Execution will stop at the next **tickable** event after the connection flag is set to ABORTED - which will be detected when PHP attempts to flush output to the client

The current MySQL query will finish executing (as the next event that PHP has control over doesn't occur until after the query has completed), but your script would not make it past that, unless you explicitly set `ignore_user_abort`. It's always important to account for this when writing code.

**There are two ways around this**

1. Set `ignore_user_abort` to `true` for the invocation of your script
2. Do not print anything back to the client until after all of your processing is complete - since a connection closed status won't be detected until output is flushed

Comment: @Christopher A framework can't solve for all of your problems. Now sure how a framework can solve for this at all, actually. By, what, always setting `ignore_user_abort`? That may not be the behavior you want. You can't assume a framework will handle everything for you and you should always be sure about what it's doing.

Comment: Oh yes absolutely. Always check under the hood. By framework, I mean self-built also.

Comment: @Christopher Touche. And I will upvote you in hopes that people actually read your comment. Couldn't tell you how many people I know that use frameworks for their magic with no idea of how the magic works. Tough to control a website where 90% of the code isn't written by you.

Answer (score 0):

The Answer is it depends, as others mentioned you can check what is running on the mysql server by using the show processlist;

If it is a single query that takes a long time, the it will most likely carry on running after the browser has closed. PHP will have sent the request to the Database and will in effect be sat waiting for it to complete, in turn the browser will be waiting for the webserver to finish building the page/resource that is on that url

so the request is: browser <-> web server (<-> php ) <-> mysql in an ideal world if the user cancels the request everything would tidy itself up nicely, but that in my experience sadly is not the case, if one of the chain decides not to wait, the process that it is waiting for doesn't necessarily know until it tries to send the response back and fails